# If an operator $X$ on a Hilbert space satisfies $X^*=-X$, then is $X$ equal to $0$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

If a linear  operator $X$ on a Hilbert space satisfies $X^*=-X$, then is $X$ equal to $0$? $X^*$ is the adjoint.

Comment: What if the operator is multiplication by the imaginary unit? $i^* = -i$.

Answer (score 4):

No. Such operators called skew-symmetric. For example the matrix

$X=\begin{bmatrix}0&2&-1\\-2&0&-4\\1&4&0\end{bmatrix}$

gives a skew-symmetric operator on $\mathbb R^3$ (or  $\mathbb C^3$)